# Installing Ubuntu on devices error - fork/exec /usr/bin/xz: cannot allocate memory

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I'm trying to install Ubuntu in my nexus 10. 
I went through all steps with out any problems except at the end "Install Ubuntu using your selected channel, in this case we use the devel channel". 
Here is the result from the terminal.

```
michi@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel --bootstrap
DEPRECATED: Implicit 'touch' subcommand assumed
2014/11/10 09:52:04 Expecting the device to be in the bootloader... waiting
2014/11/10 09:52:04 Device is |manta|
2014/11/10 09:52:04 Flashing version 243 from devel channel and server https://system-image.ubuntu.com to device manta
/home/michi/.cache/ubuntuimages/ubuntu-touch/devel/manta/version-243.tar.xz
2014/11/10 09:52:15 copied 0 bytes with err: fork/exec /usr/bin/xz: cannot allocate memory
michi@ubuntu:~/Downloads$
```

Can anyone help me through this problem?